# how to edit and save rows in a table using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a page that displays all of the contents of my table. Alongisde each row of the table I also have a column containing a checkbox. I have implemented this for deleting rows. If in case i want to edit and save changes in the table how am i supposed to deal with?Below is the code which i have implemented for delete.

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("project")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM menu";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Vendor_id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Item_id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Item_name</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Price</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $rows['item_id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['vendor_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['item_id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['item_name']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['Price']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "DELETE FROM menu WHERE item_id='$del_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);}

if($result){echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=delete_menu.php\">";}}
mysql_close();
?>
</table></form></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all use PDO instead of mysql...

and for your answer ..

there are many ways to do this... but the simplest that i can think of is.. creating an edit button/(link) in each table rows. this sends the id of the data to be edited to a php page where u can do the editand saving it to the database table part...

for an example...

i will add this to your table..

HTML

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="saveEdit.php?id=".<?php echo $rows['vendor_id']; ?>EDIT</a></td>
```

this will take u to the saveEdit.php page with an id...

u can get the id value in saveEdit.php by

```
$vendor_id=$_GET['id'];
```

u have an id now...create a form...get related data of that vendor from the table and show it in the form...let user edit it...and save it to the database table..like u did, to delete the vendor..